How to easily pull changes into feature branch from main branch
My business case: we are 3 testers working on a common code base stored in the Main branch.
Last week, I started working on a new test by creating a feature branch off Main.
However before I could create a PR, the other 2 testers pushed their changes and got merged into the Main branch.
Now my problem is that my feature branch is not in sync with Main branch anymore. How do I pull the latest changes into feature from Main?
Git fetch or Git pull didn't update my feature branch, it only updated my local main branch, but my local feature branch is still not updated with latest changes from main.
How do I rebase my local feature branch with latest copy of main branch in INTELLIJ IDE Ultimate.
I get confused when selecting ACCEPT MY CHANGE or ACCEPT THEIR CHANGE.
I messed up my branch while doing that ....
How do I update my feature branch from latest copy of master without losing my local changes.
Please guide me

A variable in the flow that you should follow is that we don't know what the upstream branch of your feature branch is. The upstream branch is what would be used as the branch to rebase on if you ran git pull -r, say.... so, to avoid using the wrong upstream and assuming that your local main btanch  is already updated, you could run git rebase main (assuming you are already working on your feature branch).

Step-by-Step Instructions :

Fetch the Latest Changes from the Remote Repository
Open IntelliJ IDEA.

Navigate to VCS > Git > Fetch to fetch the latest changes from the remote repository.

Checkout Your Feature Branch
In the bottom-right corner of IntelliJ IDEA, click on the branch name to open the Branches popup.

Select your feature branch and choose Checkout.

Rebase Your Feature Branch onto the Latest Main Branch
Navigate to VCS > Git > Rebase.
Select Rebase Current Branch on....
In the dialog that appears, choose the main branch (e.g., origin/main) as the target branch and click Rebase.

Resolve Conflicts (If there are conflicts)


For each conflict, use the diff viewer provided by IntelliJ IDEA:
Accept Yours (Accept My Change): Keeps your changes and discards the incoming changes from the main branch.
Accept Theirs (Accept Their Change): Keeps the changes from the main branch and discards your changes.
Merge: Allows you to manually merge the changes by editing the file.
After resolving each conflict, mark the file as resolved by clicking the Mark as Resolved button in the upper-right corner of the diff viewer.

Continue the Rebase :

Once all conflicts are resolved, continue the rebase process.
go to VCS > Git > Rebase, then select Continue Rebase.

Push the Rebased Feature Branch :

After successfully rebasing and resolving conflicts, push your feature branch to the remote repository.
Go to VCS > Git > Push.
In the Push dialog, make sure to push your feature branch.
Use the --force-with-lease option to ensure you don’t overwrite any changes that may have been pushed by others.
